# Changing only a certain part of HTML using jQuery html.replace() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically, I am copying content of one div to other like this

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var a = $("#div1").html()
    $("#div2").html(a);
```

I want the variable 'a' to change all the occurrence of a character/string and copy it to div2.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   var a = $("#div1").html().replace("$money","$cash");
   $("#div2").html(a);
```

So, basically, I want the replace the occurrence of '$money' with '$cash' and store it inside test1. The above code copies the exact content but does not replace '$money' with '$cash'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP variables don't exist on the client.

Comment: Let's ignore PHP variables, I am editing the question.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8u91npdk/

Comment: If you want to do multiple replacements, you have to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier, not a string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: And if I want to replace $money to $cash, do I need to add something?

Comment: Replace `/$money/g` with `'$cash'`

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8u91npdk/2/

Comment: Thanks, can you kindly make one fiddle for $money to $cash

Comment: There are no PHP variables in jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the problem, I am trying to change the PHP variable with javascript, but it's not updating

Comment: Are you creating the JS with PHP? You can use `replace(/<?php echo $money; ?>/, "<?php echo $cash; ?>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape back to PHP to substitute variables into the Javascript.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   var a = $("#div1").html().replace(/<?php echo preg_quote($money); ?>/g, <?php echo json_encode($cash); ?>);
   $("#div2").html(a);
});
```

You need to use a regexp with the global modifier to perform multiple replacements.

Answer (score 0):

repeating response as @Barmar, but removing the php part to simplify

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   var a = $("#div1").html().replace(/money/g,"cash");
   $("#div2").html(a);  
 });
```